# iOS - InApp subscription - Expiry date

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

In my application, after successfully subscribing to the in-app purchase, i want to know the data of expiry and show an alert to user. (Just for information purpose). How can I do that without sending a verification receipt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this for an auto-renewing subscription? The only way you can get the actual expiration date is by verifying the receipt with Apple's servers. If you only want to display the original expiration date as a confirmation right after they subscribe, you can just calculate it based on the current date and subscription period for the product ID.

But if you want to be able to display the current expiration date at any given time, or when the subscription renews, you have to verify the receipt.